# Why do I see forward slash in one path and backslash in other?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Using pycharm 2017.3(edu) and python3.6.4

modulesTut1.py:

```
import modulesTut2
print(__file__)
```

modulesTut2.py:

```
def f():
    print("f1")
print(__file__)
v = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

**OUTPUT ::**

```
C:\Users\shashank\PycharmProjects\python_rest\modulesTut2.py
C:/Users/shashank/PycharmProjects/python_rest/modulesTuts1.py
```

It does gets fixed when I use

```
__file__ = os.path.abspath(__file__)
```

before print the __file__ variable in both the files.

Comment: Probably because Windows doesn't really care, Python uses one style when importing modules, and PyCharm uses the other when running a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phenomena is really there and seems to be very simple: for imported modules, `__file__` uses the OS-native notation, but for the main .py file you pass to Python as command-line parameter, it simply contains exactly what is supplied as parameter.

Let's say we have folders `C:\Users\me\Python\test\extra`, and files

`C:\Users\me\Python\test\a.py`:

```
import b
print(__file__)
```

`C:\Users\me\Python\test\b.py`:

```
print(__file__)
```

Then if you stay in `C:\Users\me\Python\test` and type `python a.py`, you will get

> ```
> C:\Users\me\Python\test>python a.py
> C:\Users\me\Python\test\b.py
> a.py
> ```

If you stay anywhere at all, and type full path, as `python C:\Users\me\Python\test\a.py`:

> ```
> C:\>python C:\Users\me\Python\test\a.py
> C:\Users\me\Python\test\b.py
> C:\Users\me\Python\test\a.py
> ```

However if you just switch some backslashes to forward slashes, that will work too:

> ```
> C:\>python C:\Users/me/Python\test\a.py
> C:\Users\me\Python\test\b.py
> C:\Users/me/Python\test\a.py
> ```

Relative paths appear too, including `..`:

> ```
> C:\Users\me\Python\test\extra>python ..\a.py
> C:\Users\me\Python\test\b.py
> ..\a.py
> ```
>
> or even
>
> ```
> C:\User\me\Python\test\extra>python c:../..\test\a.py
> C:\User\me\Python\test\b.py
> c:../..\test\a.py
> ```

TL;DR: PyCharm seems to pass complete path with forward slashes and that is what you get back in `__file__`.

Comment: @ShashankSingh I am not sure what you mean, TL;DR stands for "*Too long; didn't read*".

Comment: Ohh didn't know that. Thank u